# Как переместиться на определённую строку кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В самом внизу кода есть строки предназначенные для возвращения к нужной части кода или окончание цикла и завершение программы.
Я пытался использовать и с True и переделка переменных и множество функций, но ничего не помогало.
Основная задача это при вводе "да" он должен возвращаться на строку while True:  pog = True
При введении отсебятины он должен вернуться к вопросу (повторить [да/нет])

```
# обозначение переменных.
while True:
        pog = True
        a = float(input('Введите кол-во потребляемого электричества заводом в Ua: '))
        b = float(input('Введите потери сети в Ua: '))
        c = float(input('Введите кол-во доступной энергии в Ua: '))
        d = float(0.75)
        # расчёт суммы переменных и результат расчётов.
        f=float(a+b);
        print('Кол-во потерь и потребляемого электричества: ', f)
        print('Производятся подведение итогов...Подождите.')
        if a + b <= c:
            print('В норме.')
        elif a + b <= c*d:
            print('Близко к нехватке энергии.')
        else:
            print('Нехватка энергии.')
        something = True
# перезагрузка программы при вводе слова "да" и его выключение при вводе слова "нет".
while something:
    flag = input('Повтор? [да/нет]: ')
    if flag == 'да':
        pog = False
    elif flag == 'нет':
            break
    else:
            something = False
```

Comment: Сделай функции и делай вызов когда нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

подвинь цикл внутрь основного

```
while True:
        pog = True
        a = float(input('Введите кол-во потребляемого электричества заводом в Ua: '))
        b = float(input('Введите потери сети в Ua: '))
        c = float(input('Введите кол-во доступной энергии в Ua: '))
        d = float(0.75)
        # расчёт суммы переменных и результат расчётов.
        f=float(a+b);
        print('Кол-во потерь и потребляемого электричества: ', f)
        print('Производятся подведение итогов...Подождите.')
        if a + b <= c:
            print('В норме.')
        elif a + b <= c*d:
            print('Близко к нехватке энергии.')
        else:
            print('Нехватка энергии.')
        something = True
    # перезагрузка программы при вводе слова "да" и его выключение при вводе слова "нет".
    while something:
        flag = input('Повтор? [да/нет]: ')
        if flag == 'да':
            pog = False
        elif flag == 'нет':
            pog = True
        else:
            something = False
    if pog:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# обозначение переменных.
something = True
def start(pog=True):
    while True:
            a = float(input('Введите кол-во потребляемого электричества заводом в Ua: '))
            b = float(input('Введите потери сети в Ua: '))
            c = float(input('Введите кол-во доступной энергии в Ua: '))
            d = float(0.75)
            # расчёт суммы переменных и результат расчётов.
            f=float(a+b);
            print('Кол-во потерь и потребляемого электричества: ', f)
            print('Производятся подведение итогов...Подождите.')
            if a + b <= c:
                print('В норме.')
            elif a + b <= c*d:
                print('Близко к нехватке энергии.')
            else:
                print('Нехватка энергии.')
            something = True
# перезагрузка программы при вводе слова "да" и его выключение при вводе слова "нет".
while something:
    flag = input('Повтор? [да/нет]: ')
    if flag == 'да':
        start(False)
    elif flag == 'нет':
        break
    else:
        something = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Заодно выкинул лишние переменные.

```
while True:
        a = float(input('Введите кол-во потребляемого электричества заводом в Ua: '))
        b = float(input('Введите потери сети в Ua: '))
        c = float(input('Введите кол-во доступной энергии в Ua: '))
        d = float(0.75)
        # расчёт суммы переменных и результат расчётов.
        f=float(a+b);
        print('Кол-во потерь и потребляемого электричества: ', f)
        print('Производятся подведение итогов...Подождите.')
        if a + b <= c:
            print('В норме.')
        elif a + b <= c*d:
            print('Близко к нехватке энергии.')
        else:
            print('Нехватка энергии.')

        # перезагрузка программы при вводе слова "да" и его выключение при вводе слова "нет".
        while True:
            flag = input('Повтор? [да/нет]: ').lower()
            if flag in ('да', 'нет'):
                break
        if flag == "нет":
            break
```

Comment: "не лишние, а запасные" )